# Where to find list of exceptions and when their occurs

Tags: java, database, spring

I am using `SimpleJdbcTemplate` to connect to database. Where I can found all exception and also when they are thrown? I know just few for example:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException
```

occurs when the SQL query has bad grammar. But I need to know more for example what exception is thrown when database is unreachble or there is lock etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the API of `SimpleJdbcTempate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html). I find this exceptions:

- [`DataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html)

which has these known subclasses:

- [`NonTransientDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/NonTransientDataAccessException.html) with subclasses:

  - `CleanupFailureDataAccessException`
  - `DataIntegrityViolationException`
  - `DataRetrievalFailureException`
  - `DataSourceLookupFailureException`
  - `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`
  - `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException`
  - `NonTransientDataAccessResourceException`
  - `PermissionDeniedDataAccessException`
  - `UncategorizedDataAccessException`
- [`RecoverableDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/RecoverableDataAccessException.html)
- [`TransientDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/TransientDataAccessException.html) with subclasses:

  - `ConcurrencyFailureException`
  - `QueryTimeoutException`
  - `TransientDataAccessResourceException`

Read the [documentation on `JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate) in the Spring guide, too.

Answer (score 0):

In general you are looking for all subclasses of [`DataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html), starting from: [`TransientDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/TransientDataAccessException.html), [`NonTransientDataAccessException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/NonTransientDataAccessException.html) and [RecoverableDataAccessException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/RecoverableDataAccessException.html). Keep looking for subclasses.

There are plenty of such exceptions, you must read the JavaDocs to understand when they are thrown. Spring does a pretty good job of translating database-specific exceptions into standard hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Spring API

```
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/
```

a couple of exceptions list ...

```
BadSqlGrammarException 
CannotGetJdbcConnectionException 
IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException 
InvalidResultSetAccessException 
JdbcUpdateAffectedIncorrectNumberOfRowsException 
LobRetrievalFailureException 
SQLWarningException 
UncategorizedSQLException
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find these details in the JavaDoc for the framework. [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/) are the 3.0.x docs. If you look in the package org.springframework.jdbc  you will find several exceptions listed.